# Dynamically set identity field on/off in nHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate, spring.net, ddl

I'm new to NHibernate/Spring and I have a query that requires the identity column to be OFF before running the query and turned ON afterwards. Basically, we're reinserting a record into a table from a log table and we need to keep the ID the same.

When I try to do the "SET IDENTITY_INSERT primarykeyfield OFF", Hibernate says it cannot execute because it expects a SELECT or INSERT first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute a SQL command as HQL.

Use `CreateSQLQuery` instead of `CreateQuery`.

Comment: Should I execute the CreateSQLQuery first (SET IDENTITY OFF) and then create another query (using CreateQuery) to move the records and execute? Then execute another statement (SET IDENTITY ON) using CreateSQLQuery?

Comment: @osij2is: Yes. But if your entity is using an identity generator, you won't be able to insert a specific value using HQL. You might have to use SQL for that too.

Comment: Our table is using the native identity generator. Is it just not possible to turn off/on the identity property on that Id?